# How return the total entries in our JSON API if we use pagination by Link Header

Tags: api, rest

I start implement a REST API. I have a request doing on a resource with multiple entries. To implement the pagination, I do like Github choose implement it.

I define a [HTTP Header Link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/9707-link-header.html) where I add the next/previous/first/last link.

```
Link: <https://api.github.com/repos?page=3&per_page=100>; rel="next",
  <https://api.github.com/repos?page=50&per_page=100>; rel="last"
```

In my body there are only my entries and nothing else. But Now I want know how entries there are in total. I can't do a multiplication between number of page and per_page entries, because the result is not exact.

So how can I do to return this number to entries ? I think add a new HTTP Header in my answer `X-total-entries`. But I don't know if there are better technique or not.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to decide whether to put some data into the headers or into the body, I ask myself if it is a feature of the application or of the protocol? In your case, is the pagination a feature of the application? Is the user aware what page he is looking at? Is the total number of items displayed to the user? If the answer is yes, then I would put the information into the body. Then the body becomes not just a list of items, but a representation of a page, with all the information and controls needed to display it. Only if the pagination is a internal protocol detail would I consider putting the links and the item count into the header. I know this may sound a rather abstract way of thinking, but if the pagination details need to bubble up all the way to the top of the application, there is little real benefit in separating this information from the body and putting it into the headers.